# Camera Access in Google Mirror API

Tags: java, php, camera, google-mirror-api

I see that developers can now create web applications using PHP for Google Glass. This is great but I don't see anything about accessing the device's camera for picture taking and video recording. Is this possible? I was initially planning on developing a Glass app that uses the camera in Java. If that is the only way to do it (meaning it can't be done using the mirror API and PHP) where is documentation for creating apps that actually reside on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Mirror API model for Glass development, a Glass user would share with your Glassware a picture or video that they have taken. This puts them in control of the camera and the output of it. See https://developers.google.com/glass/stories#add_a_cat_to_that for a general work flow of how this would be done. https://developers.google.com/glass/contacts has details about how to add your Glassware as a contact, and https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions for how your Glassware gets notified when something is shared with it.

There is native access via sideloading, but this is generally discouraged since it creates an environment that is very un-Glass-like. Although they have announced a development kit to help support this for the future, it is still being designed (with input from the community), and there have been no announcements about how they will support having apps loaded onto Glass in the future.

In general, you should be planning to write Glassware with the Mirror API and carefully understand what you're doing before going the app route.